# Cross platform Windows, Android and iOS apps development on a Mac computer using Visual Studio 2017 environment setup

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017, macos-sierra

Let's say my physical Environment is a Mac computer with Windows 10 installed using Bootcamp and also the same Windows 10 running on a Virtual Machine. (I think this is possible with some VM software)

With Visual Studio 2017 running under Windows is it possible to connect to MacOS to compile iOS part of the apps? How?

I think I cannot develop Windows Apps using Visual Studio 2017 for Mac so that option is out of question.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: just googled that for you (type "visual studio ios" in google...): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx (vs2015)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/cross-platform-mobile-development-in-visual-studio (vs2017)

Comment: Thanks. I read those articles before. They do not answer my question. My question is if both Windows and MacOS is on the same Mac computer and if I am developing cross platform xamarin apps with VS 2017 on Windows on that same Mac computer how I connect to MacOS to compile iOS part of the apps.

Comment: Ok to clarify your question: You installed windows on your Mac computer, why would you use visual studio for mac? You can just use the normal visual studio in windows to develop windows apps and compile them on a IOS vm for mac (connect the IOS vm via xamarin in visual studio)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the setup and installation documentation. Basically you need to install Visual Studio for Mac on your Mac and Visual Studio 2017 in your virtual machine.

You then need to connect via the build agent (Visual Studio will show you how). This can all be done on the same machine if you are using a Mac.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/